# How can I return two DStreams in a function after using the filter transformation in spark streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

In a function, is there a way to return two DStreams after using `filter` ?
For example when I filter a `DStream`, the filtered ones will be stored in a `DStream` and the unfiltered ones will be stored in another `DStream`.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done more efficiently if it was built-in, but

```
def partition[A](stream: DStream[A])(pred: A => Boolean) {
  val stream1 = stream.map(x => (x, pred(x)).cache()
  val good = stream1.filter(_._2).map(_._1)
  val bad = stream1.filter(!_._2).map(_._1)
  (good, bad)
}
```

Note `cache()` is required to make sure `stream1` is only calculated once; if `pred` is simple enough, and `stream` is already cached, just `(stream.filter(pred), stream.filter(x => !pred(x)))` should be faster.

Comment: But the DStream at first contains filtered and unfiltered elements. I want to return the filtered and unfiltered in the same time !

Comment: So you don't mean "unfiltered", you mean "filtered with the opposite predicate"? I.e. a function which works like `partition` on Scala collections)?

Comment: Oh I think so ! It is "filtered with the opposite predicate"